# Migrating to SQL Server 2016 - Data migration Assitant

Tags: sql-server, upgrade, database-migration, sql-server-2016

I'm in a migration project from SQL Server 2005 to SQL Server 2016. First step was using the upgrade advisor and search for incompatibilities. Checked that it was replaced with Microsoft® Data Migration Assistant V1.0. I didn't find any option for analyzing trace files in it. Any alternative for that? We have applications that run ad-hoc queries. This way, running the Migration Assistant directly on the database will be useless. I need to check a trace file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot migrate from SQL Server 2005 to SQL Server 2016 directly, you would have to migrate it to a SQL Server 2008/2008R2/2012 instance first otherwise you will have trouble with [database compatibility level](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510680.aspx). Data Migration Assistant(2.0 is out now) doesn't have the ability to analysis trace file yet you would have to use [SQL Server 2014 Upgrade Adviso](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn236457(v=sql.120).aspx)r instead.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Lin. I'm doing that (using 2014 Upgrade Advisor), but unfurtonately it is not the best scenario, since i'm migrating to SQL 2016. Hope Microsoft release this feature soon.